# Entity Framework 5 how to specify a criteria on navigation property

Tags: entity-framework-5

in C# Entity Framework 5 I have

```
class Order {
  // ....
     public bool IsArchived {get; set;}
}

class Customer { 

  [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
  public /*virtual*/ IList<Order> Orders {get; set;}
}
```

all is fine the Orders per customer load up nicely. But I just want the orders where IsArchived is false, due to there are too many old orders I do not require. Is there any way to eager load only the non archived orders. Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: If it's lazy loading, you will "load" the related entities only when needed. So why bother ? You will "load" only the one you need, won't you ?

Comment: every month a customer orders about 50 orders... so it gets really huge. I just need the non archived ones every where in the code. would this not be easy having EF loading only the non archived orders instead of declaring an extra property `public IList<Order> ActiveOrders { get { return orders.where(o=>!o.IsArchied;)}}` there is simply too much data in there thats not required for the project. I could write `ctx.Customers.Include("Orders") ... ` but all i need is the non archived orders

Comment: i will be serializing the customers along with their orders to json. so i suppose I would end up accessing all the orders/per customer anyways and things will get loaded... not sure i could explain the situation